# Can't boot into ubuntu after installing

Tags: 12.04, hp

I just installed Ubuntu at my HP Pavillion H8 computer with 8gb RAM and a Intel Core i7 CPU, and for some reason I can't boot into Ubuntu. When looking in the msconfig boot menu, the only OS listed is Windows 7. Also I can't seem to find the "OS selection screen" in my boot menu. When the HP logo appears, I press esc to interrupt normal boot, and I get this screen with a lot of options. I tried all of them, and none of them seems to have a "OS Selection Screen".

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 using a CD.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I read this article, which said that Ubuntu made itself the default OS when installed. That's not the case here. I can't even get into it. http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/bootmenu

EDIT2: I've just checked my remaining space in the C: drive in Windows. And yes, the partition were successfull, I have less space for Windows (which means more space for Ubuntu, I think). So from that I can conclude that my installation weren't cancelled.

Comment: Did you boot the CD in EFI or IDE mode when installing?

Comment: I'm new to Linux and everything regarding multiple OS's. So I can't answer that question. I'm sorry. All I did was interrupting normal startup, then select "Boot options" and then picking the first option which contained CD-DVR.

Comment: You can check that in the BIOS, probably under "Boot" options! My advice is to try and change it to the other (EFI to IDE or the other way around) and reinstall Ubuntu. I had a similar problem once, because the bootloader (GRUB) was not being installer correctly in one of the modes.

Comment: I'll try that out! :) Can you add it as an answer, so I can tick as the correct answer?

Comment: See this question for possible issues with Windows 8 computers that come with UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Boot repair disk ISO. Link for boot repair disk: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/
2. Using universal USB installer create bootable USB with Boot repair disk ISO. Universal USB installer link: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
3. Restart the computer with the USB flash drive. Keep pressing F8/12 or ESC depending on your computer and select boot option.
4. Select USB flash.
5. Computer will be booted with boot repair disk. Select the option for repairing grub.
6. Restart your computer, it will be ok.

Comment: Hi Ashok, I am able to boot into boot repair on the USB in Legacy mode but not UEFI mode as shown here: https://imgur.com/a/mMAuT8l and here: https://imgur.com/a/lndJ8Jn.